# Windows 7 Editions compatibility on a netbook

Tags: windows, multi-boot, netbook, intel-atom

I have an ASUS EeePC 1015CX netbook currently running Windows 7 Starter Edition. I wanted to install Windows 7 Enterprise. Would it work well? (I don't mind disabling things like AERO Glass stuff to squeeze out more power).

Also how can I do a dual booting so that I don't delete the original system in case this doesn't work?

Comment: the 32Bit version should work. But the maximum RAM of 2GB maybe too low if you use enterprise features/programs.

Comment: Just to clarify that the netbook has 1GB of RAM.

Comment: ok, in this case stay at the starter edition

Answer (score 1):

With the specifications for your netbook, there's no reason why this shouldn't work just fine. Especially if you look at [the minimum requirements for Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/system-requirements).

Clearly, you'll need to install the drivers for your netbook - but the differences between *Starter* and *Enterprise* lie not in the core department, and thus that shouldn't be a problem.

*I would note however that I highly doubt you havea volume license agreement, and thus installing Windows 7 Enterprise seems highly unlikely to be "legit". Just saying!*

Comment: It's good to know that it would work. Could you please tell me how to partition the drive so that I don't loose any original data during installation.

Oh I just realized how shady the description of the system looks like, sorry about that! It is an evaluation version that I want to use to test it, it has the highest specifications so if that works anything should.